# RGBA buffer to JPEG libjpeg-turbo

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write the RGBA pixels I have into a JPEG image buffer using libjpeg-turbo as they support RGBA.
Originally I was writing RGB to buffer using [RGB buffer to JPEG buffer, what is wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482812/rgb-buffer-to-jpeg-buffer-what-is-wrong-here) with JPEG-8 but now I need to write RGBA. Unfortunately the outright jpeg-8 lib doesn't support RGBA from the available colors to select, so libjpeg-turbo has caught my eye. Replacing jpeg-8 with libjpeg-turbo compiles everything nicely but setting JCS_EXT_RGBA yields Bogus color space. I'm reading the README on the github but it doesn't quite say outright how to have run-time support RGBA?

Any thoughts on previous users?

Comment: Why can't you use Opencv? Here is an example of storing BGRA image, https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: @ranka47 The source code I was using is identical to the one in the question linked above.